# Button Action on login Button click in FBConnect API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fbconnect

I am using fbconnect api in my project.When the login dialog gets opened where we entered our credentials ,when I click on login button there is something performed and it is redirected to the publish page.
My problem is I am not getting which action is performed on that login button so that I can put an indicator over there.

I have attached a screenshot to specify which button I am talking about.
[image]

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do you want to steal others' Facebook passwords? :)

It seems, `FBConnect` uses `UIWebView` to load the pages from web. Those form elements are not created from the code. So you can not have the access to those methods/actions.

---

**Tracking the *login button* action using *UIWebViewDelegate***:

In `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method in `FBDialog.m`, you can see the request which are sent from the login view.

You can read the `URL` by using `[request.URL absoluteString]`. 
Check if that *URL* contains the string `https://www.facebook.com/login.php?m=m`. If it is *YES* then probably a login request is being sent. You can do your action there.

*Note: I am not sure this will always work. You can do further research to find a better solution.*

Comment: Here is standard Facebook dialog that appears when device is not support multitasking.

Comment: @Simon no my requirement is when I click this button activity indicator gets opened until new dialog gets open.

Comment: @Gypsa, You want to show an activity indicator when user taps the login button? FBConnect already displays an activity indicator, right?

Comment: no it dont display on clicking login button which is shown in screenshot

Comment: @Gypsa, Ok. You don't want to display an activity indicator when the login button is pressed. What you want to do when the login button is pressed?

Comment: @Simon: I mean the screenshot in question.

Comment: @Gypsa: as say Simon - you need to use UIWebViewDelegate to catch login action

Answer (score 1):

When you push login button - the login request will send to FB server only. To get answer you need to implement FBSessionDelegate protocol:

```
/**
 * Called when the user successfully logged in.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogin;

/**
 * Called when the user dismissed the dialog without logging in.
 */
- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled;

/**
 * Called when the user logged out.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogout;
```

Read also comments in Facebook.m:

- Starts a dialog which prompts the user to log in to Facebook and grant
- the requested permissions to the application.
  *
- If the device supports multitasking, we use fast app switching to show
- the dialog in the Facebook app or, if the Facebook app isn't installed,
- in Safari (this enables single sign-on by allowing multiple apps on
- the device to share the same user session).
- When the user grants or denies the permissions, the app that
- showed the dialog (the Facebook app or Safari) redirects back to
- the calling application, passing in the URL the access token
- and/or any other parameters the Facebook backend includes in
- the result (such as an error code if an error occurs).

Comment: NOTE: if you use "authorize" method from Facebook.h and see this dialog - then you device not support multitasking.

Comment: @Gypsa: as say Simon - you need to use UIWebViewDelegate to catch login action. And I didn't find any other approach.